# jQuery hover and unhover

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
    $('a.uiPopup').hover(function () {          
            $('.uiTip').show();
        },
        function () {
            $('.uiTip').remove();
        });

        $('div.uiTip').live("mouseover", function () {
            $(this).stop(true, true).show();
        });
        $('div.uiTip').live("mouseleave", function () {
            $(this).remove(); });
        });
```

So when you hover `uiPopup` then `uiTip` appears and then when you unhover it dissapears again BUT if you were to hover over the tip it would stop the tip from being removed and keep it on screen until your mouseleaves and then remove it.

Doesn't work though :/ Any ideas? Thank you

**The `.remove()` is intentionally as in my real script (this being a snippet to show my example) I am using AJAX to load in the .uiHelp and they have unqiue ids (again not shown in the above example as beyond the scope of question) Which all works fine just not the bit about stopping it when the user hovers the tip itself!**

EDIT: For those that want to see the full script and why I have to use the hover:

```
$('a.uiPopup').hover(function () {
            $tip = '<div class="uiTip uiOverlayArrowLeft loading"><div class="uiOverlayContent"><!--content here --></div><i class="uiOverlayArrow"></i></div>';

            $newtip = $($tip).attr('id', 'organisationId-' + $(this).attr('id'));

            $($newtip).find('.uiOverlayContent').load(AppURL + 'Organisations/Manage/Tip', function () { $($newtip).removeClass('loading') });

            $('body').append($newtip);

            $location = $(this).offset(); $top = $location.top; $left = $location.left; $right = $location.right; $bottom = $location.bottom;

            $left = $left + $(this).width();
            $left = $left + 8;

            $top = $top - 10;

            $($newtip).css({
                'top': $top + 'px',
                'left': $left + 'px'
            });
        },
        function () {
            $id = "div#organisationId-" + $(this).attr('id');
            $($id).remove();
        });

        $('div.uiTip').live("mouseover", function () {
            $(this).stop(true, true).show();
        });
        $('div.uiTip').live("mouseleave", function () {
            $(this).remove(); });
        });
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `.hide()` instead of `.remove`?

Comment: No because I want it removing from the DOM!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you mention *uiTip* in one snippet and *uiHelp* in another. Is the *uiTip* somewhere inside the *uiHelp* div? If so, the problem is that your mouse leaves the link to get on top of the tooltip div, and so it is removed before your mouse is ever considered "over" the div.

Here's a possible solution:

```
$('a.uiPopup').hover(function () {
  $('.uiHelp').show();
}, function () {
  $('.uiHelp').data('timer', setTimeout(function () {
    $('.uiHelp').remove();
  }, 100));
});

$('div.uiHelp').live('mouseover', function () {
  if ($(this).data('timer')) {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
  }
});

$('div.uiHelp').live('mouseleave', function () {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

This gives the user a tenth of a second to get from the link over the tooltip, before it disappears. You can adjust that time in the *setTimeout* call.

I'll leave it up to you to sort out uiTip/uiHelp - you just need somewhere to store the reference to the timer.

Comment: Just on a side note, in the latest versions of JQuery .live() is deprecated, you should use .on()

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help u

```
$('a.uiPopup').hover(function () {          
    $('.uiHelp').show();
},function (e) {
    if(!$(e.target).parents('div.uiTip').length)
       $('.uiHelp').remove();
});
$('div.uiTip').live("mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Can't do that as I need both the functions in my hover() see my updated OP for example of the real script

Comment: so check it again maybe this one will helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you should used hide() instead of .remove(), since you want to hide it and not remove the mark up from the DOM.

Comment: Actually I do want to remove it from the DOM!